# illegal text block open delimiter sequence, missing line terminator

Tags: java, string, delimiter, java-13

Java 13 is coming, so I started studying its new features, one of which is *text blocks*.

I wrote a simple program

```
public final class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String greeting = """Hello
        It's me, Andrew!""";
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}
```

I was expecting to see

```
Hello
It's me, Andrew!
```

What I got is a compilation error saying

> illegal text block open delimiter sequence, missing line terminator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The context of your text block must start from a new line.

```
public final class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String greeting = """
            Hello
            It's me, Andrew!""";
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Hello
It's me, Andrew!
```

An excerpt from [JEP 355: Text Blocks (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355):

> A text block consists of zero or more content characters, enclosed by opening and closing delimiters.
>
> The opening delimiter is a sequence of three double quote characters (`"""`) followed by zero or more white spaces **followed by a line terminator**. The content begins at the first character after the line terminator of the opening delimiter.

You don't necessarily have to put a line terminator at the end of your content, though.

> The closing delimiter is a sequence of three double quote characters. **The content ends at the last character before the first double quote of the closing delimiter.**

```
final String greeting = """
    Hello
    It's me, Andrew!
    """;
```

would mean

```
Hello
It's me, Andrew!
<an empty line here>
```

I find it extremely unclear, so I had to share this with the community.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, [a rationale for the decision not to allow content immediately after `"""` is given here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html)

> The reason for this is that text blocks are primarily designed to support multi-line strings, and requiring the initial line terminator simplifies the indentation handling rules