# JDK 13 preview feature :Textblock returns false for equals and == .Is the tab spaces dependent?

Tags: java, textblock, java-13, preview-feature

`equals` and `==` return `false` for a text block string, though they print the same in the console.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonLiteral = ""
                + "{\n"
                + "\tgreeting: \"Hello\",\n"
                + "\taudience: \"World\",\n"
                + "\tpunctuation: \"!\"\n"
                + "}\n";

        String jsonBlock = """
                {
                    greeting: "Hello",
                    audience: "World",
                    punctuation: "!"
                }
                """;

        System.out.println(jsonLiteral.equals(jsonBlock)); //false
        System.out.println(jsonBlock == jsonLiteral);
    }
}
```

What is it I am missing?

Comment: Try making the spaces visible, e.g. `s = s.replace(' ', '_').replace('\t', '~')` and see if you can now spot the difference.

Comment: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-13-guide/   --  after the compiler processed them, they are absolutely indistinguishable from strings created by literals. That means jsonLiteral.equals(jsonBlock) is true and, thanks to String interning, even jsonLiteral == jsonBlock is.

Comment: Regardless, you shouldn't be relying on `==` to compare strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make the `String`s shorter.

```
String jsonLiteral = ""
        + "{\n"
        + "\tgreeting: \"Hello\"\n"
        + "}\n";

String jsonBlock = """
        {
            greeting: "Hello"
        }
        """;
```

Let's debug them and print their actual content.

```
"{\n\tgreeting: \"Hello\"\n}\n"
"{\n    greeting: \"Hello\"\n}\n"
```

`\t` and `"    "` (four ASCII SP characters, or four spaces) aren't equal, neither are the whole `String`s. As you may have noticed, the indentation in the text block was formed by spaces (not by horizontal tabs, or form feeds, or any other whitespace-like characters).

Here are some examples of text blocks from [the specification for JEP 355](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/preview/text-blocks.html):

> ```
> String season = """
>                 winter""";    // the six characters w i n t e r
>
> String period = """
>                 winter
>                 """;          // the seven characters w i n t e r LF
>
> String greeting = 
>     """
>     Hi, "Bob"
>     """;        // the ten characters H i , SP " B o b " LF
>
> String salutation =
>     """
>     Hi,
>      "Bob"
>     """;        // the eleven characters H i , LF SP " B o b " LF
>
> String empty = """
>                """;      // the empty string (zero length)
>
> String quote = """
>                "
>                """;      // the two characters " LF
>
> String backslash = """
>                    \\
>                    """;  // the two characters \ LF
> ```

In your case,

> ```
> String jsonBlock = """
>           {
>               greeting: "Hello"
>           }
>           """; // the 26 characters { LF SP SP SP SP g r e e t i n g : SP " H e l l o " LF } LF
> ```

To make them equal, replace `"\t"` with `"    "`. Both `equals` and `==` should return `true`, though you shouldn't rely on the latter.

---

**To read:**

1. [Specification for JEP 355: Text Blocks (Preview)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/preview/text-blocks.html)

**Related:**

1. [How the intents processed in a Text block(Java 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58030419/how-the-intents-processed-in-a-text-blockjava-13)
2. [illegal text block open delimiter sequence, missing line terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853217/illegal-text-block-open-delimiter-sequence-missing-line-terminator)